# Clonezilla fails to back up

Tags: usb, backup, usb-drive, clone, clonezilla

I'm trying to back up USB stick using Clonezilla and I'm getting the following messages: 
Starting to clone device (/dev/sdf5) to image(.)
Reading Super Block
extfsclone.c: FS contains a file system with errors

Answer (score 1):

Run `fsck /dev/sdf5` to check the file system for errors.

This can preferably be done from Clonezilla, as the filesystem is unmounted when booted in clonezilla.